# Objective-c, SpriteKit particles not removed after action finished

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, particle-system, skemitternode

I'm making a game in Xcode, with SpriteKit and I've encountered a problem while working with particles.

Method of Initializing SKEmitterNode:

```
-(SKEmitterNode *)newExplosionEmitter {
NSString *explosionPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"explosionH" ofType:@"sks"];
SKEmitterNode *explosion = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:explosionPath];
return explosion;
```

}

This method of my mine is the AI of CPU1, which is called in the update method.

```
-(void)CPU1AI {
SKSpriteNode *CPU1 = (SKSpriteNode *)[self childNodeWithName:CPU1CategoryName];

int aiX = CPU1.position.x;
int aiY = CPU1.position.y;
int ballX = self.ball.position.x;
int ballY = self.ball.position.y;

if ((aiY-ballY)<250 && !CPU1isDead) {
    //CPU1 AI

}
if (CPU1isDead) {
    float posY = CPU1.position.y;
    float centerX = self.frame.size.width/2;
    CGPoint goToPos = CGPointMake(centerX, posY);

    SKAction *moveToPoint = [SKAction moveTo:goToPos duration:3];
    SKAction *removeNode = [SKAction removeFromParent];
    SKAction *CPUdead = [SKAction runBlock:^{CPU1isDead = NO;}];
    SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[moveToPoint, removeNode, CPUdead]];
    explosion.position = CPU1.position;
    explosion.zPosition = 10;
    [CPU1 runAction:sequence];
    if (![explosion hasActions]) {
        explosion = [self newExplosionEmitter];
        [self addChild:explosion];
        [explosion runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction fadeAlphaTo:0.5 duration:3.5],[SKAction removeFromParent]]]];
    }
}
[explosion removeAllChildren];
}
```

After the  SK runActions ended, I put "[explosion removeAllChildren]" just to make sure my particles will be removed, but with or without it, one is still left in the memory ( I guess ) and is still buffering.
Is it because I declared it as a static SKEmitterNode in my scene ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: can you show newExplosionEmitter please? because it looks like you need to remove explosion itself from parent in this case. Not sure though.

Comment: Edit that into you first post please :)
And as you are not removing the Emitter from parent that might be the problem.
Instead of [explosion removeAllChildren] try [explosion removeFromParent]

Comment: In the explosion's runAction's sequence, the last step is to remove it from parent. That's why I don't understand why doesn't it remove it by that.

Comment: You are right. Oversaw that. Sorry!
I'll test that as soon as I'm home. But i guess there will be an answer earlier :)

Comment: What is left in the scene? A particle or the emitter?

Comment: I don't really know. I guess it's an emitter, but the only thing I see is that I've got 60-70+ more nodes in the scene than I should have :\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add these methods to your SKScene subclass (code from Apple's website that I modified slightly)...

```
- (SKEmitterNode*) newExplosionNode: (CFTimeInterval) explosionDuration
{
    SKEmitterNode *emitter =  [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"explosionH" ofType:@"sks"]];

    // Explosions always place their particles into the scene.
    emitter.targetNode = self;

    // Stop spawning particles after enough have been spawned.
    emitter.numParticlesToEmit = explosionDuration * emitter.particleBirthRate;

    // Calculate a time value that allows all the spawned particles to die. After this, the emitter node can be removed.

    CFTimeInterval totalTime = explosionDuration + emitter.particleLifetime+emitter.particleLifetimeRange/2;
    [emitter runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction fadeAlphaTo:0.5 duration:totalTime],
                                            [SKAction removeFromParent]]]];
    return emitter;
}

- (void)createExplosionAtPosition:(CGPoint)position
{
    SKEmitterNode *explosion = [self newExplosionNode:3.5];
    explosion.position = position;
    explosion.zPosition = 10;
    [self addChild:explosion];
}
```

Remove the following from your code...

```
explosion.position = CPU1.position;
explosion.zPosition = 10;
[CPU1 runAction:sequence];
if (![explosion hasActions]) {
    explosion = [self newExplosionEmitter];
    [self addChild:explosion];
    [explosion runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction fadeAlphaTo:0.5 duration:3.5],[SKAction removeFromParent]]]];
}
```

and replace it with this

```
[self createExplosionAtPosition:CPU1.position];
```

I suspect you want to set CPU1isDead = NO in the if statement, so the code isn't executed multiple times. You should also delete [explosion removeAllChildren].

Comment: No it didn't work that way :(
Anyways. I went back to my first version of this code, and it works, the only problem is that if fadeAlpaTo:0.5 duration:3 SKAction gets executed at the last moment than it's going to last for 3 more seconds, but I've already managed to overcome that mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

Just to help somebody else looking for the same answer I tried this
the one above didn't work for me either - But put me on the right track.

```
-(void)addTimeBonusParticles
{
    SKAction *remove = [SKAction performSelector:@selector(StopParticlesFlame) onTarget:self];
    SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration: .5];
    SKAction* blockAction = [SKAction runBlock:^

                             {

                                 NSString *file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"TimeBonusMagic" ofType:@"sks"];
                                 stars = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:file];
                                 [self addChild:stars];
                                 stars.zPosition = 5;
                                 stars.position = CGPointMake(countDown.position.x, countDown.position.y);


                             }];

    [self runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[blockAction,wait,remove]]];
}
```